# ZAP Scanner Issue

Tags: handshake-failure, zap-scanner

We are currently using a Web service Secured  URL for SAP using two way SSL with  Authentication based on **User Name** and **Password**

[image]

Scanning the above URL directly in **URL to attack** it results in **handshake failure**.

We have also added ZAP certificate in SAP.  Is there a way in ZAP to provide the User Name and Password for the same? What could have been the problem?

Comment: @crmprogdev I have explained my requirement clearly in this question I hope

Comment: Sounds like a TLS issue.

Comment: Hey guys, this question has more detail so I merged the other question into it.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the documents you uploaded or understanding the design of your offering, you are not going to get resolution on this developer forum, nor is this the appropriate venue to resolve your issue.

Please create a case in [partner community](http://partners.salesforce.com/) instead.